# Issues configuring my svn environment

Tags: ubuntu, svn, apache-http-server

I would like to install all what i need to start using svn for my source code, since i dont need to share my project i'm fine with doing everything on my localhost.
My final goal is to connect to the repository on my localhost with Eclipse via subclipse.
So, here all the steps i did
I have installed svn ,apache2 and libapache2-svn web server on my ubuntu machine:

```
 which svn
   /usr/bin/svn

which apache2
/usr/sbin/apache2
```

I have created a new sites in the /etc/apache2/sites-available/ directoy, a test site called svn, with the following conf:

```
<VirtualHost *>
LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so
ServerName svn.vd-devel
DocumentRoot /var/svn/guidasvn/
<Location /repos>
DAV svn
SVNPath /var/svn/guidasvn
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have then enabled the new site:

```
a2ensite svn
```

Which appears under the folder sites-enabled.
Restarted the server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

At this point i would expect everything to be fine, but, when i go to eclipse and do

```
 `Window>Open perspective>SVN Repository exploring> new repository location > http://svn.vd-devel/repo`s
```

I get the message that the location cannot be resolved, also if from the browser i do:
(h)ttp://svn.vd-devel/repos then i get no answer, i can ping/curl-request my localhost properly, but i think that that points to my default virtual site, how can i point it to my newly made second site?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add svn.vd-devel to you hosts file, like so:

127.0.0.1 localhost svn.vd-devel

(Just add it to the existing 127.0.0.1 line)